# How to remove application in ufw app list Available applications?

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, phpmyadmin

I want to remove Apache, Apache Full, Apache Secure in this list. 
I have Nginx server. But, when I install phpmyadmin on nginx server, I had a problem. After that I saw Apache, Apache Full, Apache Secure in Available applications list.

```
$ sudo ufw app list

Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  Nginx Full
  Nginx HTTP
  Nginx HTTPS
  OpenSSH
```

I've tried:

```
sudo service apache stop
sudo apt-get remove apache
sudo apt-get uninstall apache
sudo apt remove apache --purge
sudo apt-get remove apache
sudo apt-get purge apache
```

But not works. How to remove this three applications?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the article [Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html) of Ubuntu documentation:

> Applications that open ports can include an ufw profile, which details
>   the ports needed for the application to function properly. The
>   profiles are kept in **`/etc/ufw/applications.d`**, and can be edited if
>   the default ports have been changed.

I do not think the presence of these application profiles could be a problem in any way, but you can remove UFW's Apache profile by the command:

```
sudo rm -R /etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2*
```

---

To find which service is using `HTTP`|`HTTPS` ports `80`|`443` use this command:

```
sudo lsof -i -n -P +c 0 | grep ':80\|:443'
```

---

I don't know which version of Ubuntu is, but in 99% to remove Apache**2** completely you should use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove --purge apache2*
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

Comment: [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/952194/566421) is presented an example how to create your own application profile.

Comment: I dunno I could see an open port 80 with an improperly confed. instance of apache2 connected becoming a problem in the wrong neighborhood. ( :