# Accessing the web site via web server out site the LAN

Tags: server, apache2

I have installed the apache web server; with MySQL and php but am unable to access the website on `/var/www/html` from outside using my public IP address.

I have performed port forwarding on my router for the device housing the website; but when putting in the url `http://<public IP address>:8080` I receive a message saying the page cannot be found.

However if I use the url “localhost” I can see the website. What else do I need to check as clearly something has been omitted in my set up.

Comment: Do you have enabled firewall?

Comment: Would this be on the router or the ubuntu operating system; on the router, i have created pins to go out of the firewall.

Comment: I mean on the Ubuntu operating system.

Comment: I’ve just found a similar issue as a response on the forum where the questionnaire was told to disable the firewall with sudo use diable; I have done this and am now able to see my website from outside; Now I need to allow through the firewall on port 80/tcp; and am not too sure of the command for this please advise.

Comment: In short: `sudo apt install ufw`; `sudo ufw default deny incoming`; `sudo ufw default allow outgoing`; `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp`; `sudo ufw enable`

Comment: Hi, TiggersThoughts, I'm wondering, does my answer meet your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the tool Uncomplicated Firewall - [`ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ufw.8.html), at this state. It is easy to use front end of [`iptables`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/iptables.8.html). It's GUI version is called [`gufw`](http://gufw.org/).

**1.** Install the app:

```
sudo apt install ufw
```

**2.** Setup the default policy to deny all incoming traffic and allow all outgoing:

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
```

**3.** Allow the incoming traffic on certain ports. For example if your Apache server listen to port `80` use this rule:

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

Or you could use Apache's application profile:

```
sudo ufw allow Apache
```

Maybe you will want to allow the access also to the SSH port. For this case *limit* is better rule:

```
sudo ufw allow 22
```

Or use the default [application profile](https://askubuntu.com/a/952194/566421) for SSH:

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

**4.** Enable the firewall:

```
sudo ufw enable
```

References:

- [How To Set Up a Firewall with UFW on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04)
- [UFW Essentials: Common Firewall Rules and Commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)
- [Ubuntu Documentation Community Wiki: UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ufw status verbose` will show you if the firewall is active/enabled and what if any ports are allowed/blocked.

If you forwarded port 8080 on the router, make sure that it is allowed through the firewall but also make sure that Apache is listening on port `8080`. The default in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and the `sites-available` .conf files is port `80`.